# Average response time

Tags: iis, time

Im trying to find some benchmarks for average response time. We have 3 sites that have a response time between 5-7 seconds. They are US sites but their servers are located in the UK, could this have a huge negative impact on the response time. What other issues should we look for?

Thanks
Jake

Comment: Response time for what? From what? To what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UK location will add at least 70ms to your transit path.

It *is* a problem if your audience is US based because of the latency introduced for each tcp handshake.

Try the test at http://newsreports.org against your site and a US based site. It only grabs the headers, but you can see the difference even at that level.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure your website response time with online tools like

http://alertfox.com/Tools/LoadTime/

=> Just compare your site with other UK based sites.

> They are US sites but their servers are located in the UK

This will add a small, *constant* delay in the millisecond range. Unless you run game servers, that is normally not a problem. You can use the traceroute command to view the details. But again, for most site that is not an issue.